# css opacity to argb

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, image

i am trying to set a watermark (string) on a image and a pdf(with itext) with some opacity (css attribute)

so, the opacity is a float type and everything works fine with pdf because it has the method

```
PdfGState gstate = new PdfGState();
gstate.FillOpacity = textOpacity;
```

everything is ok, but for the image i am using :

```
Color color = Color.FromArgb(int alpha, Color color)
```

so my question is how to transform css opacity to alpha?

i found somewhere the formula 
opacity = (255 - transparency) / 255.0

is this correct? because when my opacity will be 1f(no opacity) the alpha will be 0 resulting to fully transparent text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula just little wrong. C# using value between 0 and 255. You using value 0..1, so formula must be like that:

```
alpha = (int)(textOpacity*255);
```